Block cipher design resources?
As someone with a PhD in theoretical crypto, block ciphers are usually just assumed to be some perfect mathematical object, which is used in various proofs... I feel like I should educate myself on how they're actually constructed. I know some basics like "S-boxes are bad for constant time implementations", but there are topics like:

The design of key schedules / round constants?
S-box design criteria?
How to measure diffusion and other desirable properties?
Statistical tests in general used in design / cryptanalysis
All sorts of criteria: algebraic degree, differential/linear branch number...
There are a gazillion attacks, so how to protect against them

If I read any paper on block ciphers I see the above stuff being thrown around without really understanding the full picture. I couldn't find any books about the topic. There are multiple nice basic tutorials about different theory topics. Examples would be e.g. https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf so I was wondering if there are any similar sorts of tutorials, papers, lectures whatnot that would get a reader to the point where they could at least have a fair shot at designing a block cipher that would withstand cryptanalysis (while not being the most efficient out there...).

I unfortunately haven't read into this topic either, but I would say one place to start is looking at things like Feistel networks and Lai-Massey. You can use an existing PRF rather than designing your own and you've made an inefficient but secure block cipher. I did this the other week using HChaCha20 for the purposes of AEAD commitment (PACT/comPACT/SC transforms using a ChaCha20 primitive rather than AES for ChaCha20-Poly1305).

We know many ways block ciphers fail, and the best justifications for security are on the line of: no known attack applies to even a reduced version of my block cipher, even though block ciphers with comparable structures have been thoroughly studied; the closest to an attack seems to be this, but it fails. Few authors seem to be willing to take the risk of theorizing cipher design beyond that, understandably so IMHO.

But, there is this site!
I suggest (humbly) that this is the best technical cryptography site on the Internet.  Just spend some time perusing it, perhaps focusing on tags that relate to your six points.  Virtually all of your questions have already been asked and answered here. Who needs books?

Though I would  counsel you to ignore one theme prevalent on this forum.  As a budding cipher designer, you will be challenged with the question of how is your novel cipher better/faster/securer than what we already have? To which you should reply that a giraffe doesn't fit into a Lamborghini. And that it's not cool nor clever to only grow potatoes in Ireland.

Hope I understood what you are looking for. In my opinion, these notes by Heys are one of the best sources to introduce the theory behind block ciphers. It doesn't cover all your topics, but it should provide a great starting point.
I would suggest implementing it and running some of the experiments with different parameters. Had a lot of fun with them!
